# Flexslider doesn't show up after loading document or window

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

i was using flexslider without checking if document/windows is loaded... but i found out a bug in my page so I was obligated to check document/window is loaded before i initialize flexslider

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // initialize flexslider
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        animationLoop: true,
        directionNav : false,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        animationDuration: 600, 
        slideshowSpeed: 5000,
    });
}
```

When i remove $(document).ready(), flexslider works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code you are missing : `);` at the end of your `}` replace it with this and check :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // initialize flexslider
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        animationLoop: true,
        directionNav : false,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        animationDuration: 600, 
        slideshowSpeed: 5000,
    });
});
```